# Stored Procedure Recordset not matching SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a very simple stored procedure, essentially a `SELECT` statement based on a view based on a single table.

When I run the `SELECT` statement separately, I am getting one set of results, and when I run the stored procedure, I am getting a different one (actually a subset of the first).

This is using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

Does anybody have any ideas how this can happen?

I have tried recompiling the stored procedure and also dropping and recreating it, and the values do not change.

The underlying table is actually a `SYNONYM` to a table in a different database but on the same server.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RPT_SelectCostCentre2]
     (@DataAreaId nvarchar(3))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        'All' AS 'NUM',
        ' All Cost Centres' AS 'Description'

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        d.NUM,
        CASE
           WHEN d.DESCRIPTION='' THEN d.NUM
           ELSE d.DESCRIPTION
        END AS 'Description'
    FROM 
        v_BAS2_Dimensions AS d
    WHERE 
        d.DataAreaId = @DataAreaId
        AND d.DIMENSIONCODE=1
    ORDER BY 
        NUM
END
```

Individual SQL Statement run to test:

```
    @DataAreaId nvarchar(4)
    --
    SET @DataAreaID='bkt2'

        SELECT 'All' AS 'NUM'
              ,' All Cost Centres' AS 'Description'
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT d.NUM
                       ,CASE
                          WHEN d.DESCRIPTION='' THEN d.NUM
                          ELSE d.DESCRIPTION
                        END AS 'Description'
          FROM v_BAS2_Dimensions AS d
          WHERE d.DataAreaId=@DataAreaId
            AND d.DIMENSIONCODE=1
          ORDER BY NUM
```

Comment: And how are we supposed to answer this without *any* SQL code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Comment: How do you declare `@DataAreaId` when run separately? Or better put the code, which shows result you expected.

Comment: And what SELECT statements are you running separately?

Comment: Added to Question. thanks.

Comment: nice one for testing our attentiveness

Answer (score 1):

You run

```
DECLARE @DataAreaId nvarchar(4)
```

And in SP:

```
@DataAreaId nvarchar(3)
```

Just fix in SP `nvarchar(4)` or even use `nvarchar(max)`